# RSACryptoServiceProvider.ImportParameters ObjectDisposedException

Tags: .net-4.0, rsacryptoserviceprovider, objectdisposedexception

We have a webservice we would like to sign an incoming request and send it further. We are using the static object of System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider and every instance is using the same static object to sign it. I read on microsoft that the static object is thread safe for this class.

Problem is that on heavy load on webservice, the signing fails with below exception:

```
    `Exception Type: System.ObjectDisposedException
Message: Safe handle's handle field can only be set if the safe handle is not closed and has a ref count of 1.
ObjectName: 
Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite: Void _ImportKey(System.Security.Cryptography.SafeProvHandle, Int32, System.Security.Cryptography.CspProviderFlags, System.Object, System.Security.Cryptography.SafeKeyHandle ByRef)
HelpLink: NULL
Source: mscorlib

StackTrace Information
****************************
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils._ImportKey(SafeProvHandle hCSP, Int32 keyNumber, CspProviderFlags flags, Object cspObject, SafeKeyHandle& hKey)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.ImportParameters(RSAParameters parameters)`
```

Comment: got a solution to put RSACryptoServiceProvider in 'USING' block and create new instance for each call. But got a feed back that its not the right way and not thread safe. it will be good if someone can share there thoughts.